# Given a connected graph $G = (V, E)$, give a polynomial time algorithm that finds the set $U \subseteq V$ with the smallest boundary

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity

So I asked something related to this a bit, but I don't think this is a duplicate in that I am providing a different version of the problem that is more generic and more easily accessible without knowing coding theory, etc.

Anyway, consider a connected graph $V = (G, E)$. For any $U \subseteq V$ the boundary of $U$ consists of edges $(u, v)$ such that $u \in U$ and $v \in V\setminus U$ or vice versa $v \in U$ and $u \in V\setminus U$ (that is, one end is in $U$ and the other isn't). Let $c(U)$ be the number of edges/size of the boundary of $U$.

Of course when $U$ is trivial, i.e, $U = \emptyset$ or $U = V$, then $c(U) = 0$. We discard these.

We want a polynomial (in $|V|$) time algorithm that finds a nontrivial set $U \subseteq V$ minimizing $c(U)$.

I was thinking of starting with the vertex of least degree $v$ and defining $U = V \setminus \{v\}$. Then we remove from the set $bdry(U) \cap nbrs(v)$ only if doing so decreases the size of the boundary. This only happens when $w\in bdry(U) \cap nbrs(v)$ is such that $nbrs(w) \cap U = \emptyset$ (that is $w$ is disconnected to the rest of $U$). This ensures that removing $w$ doesn't add new neighbors.

I'm not sure this is minimal though, and I don't know if I would call it polynomial (mostly I'm unsure how long checking degrees and neighbors takes)

Comment: This is a well-studied problem usually called min-cut. Algorithmically it is solved using a max-flow algorithm and using the max-flow min-cut theorem. So this should give you some keywords to get started.

Comment: Since this is just an undirected graph how would we orient edges to make it a flow problem?  Since ostensibly we'd want $U$ to receive and push out

Comment: Let's fix source $s$ and destination $t$. We'll try to find a minimum $s, t$-cut (i.e. a min-cut where $s,t$ are in different partitions). (1) Replace every edge by two oriented edges (one in each direction). (2) Find a max-flow from $s$ to $t$ in this directed graph. (3) Use the residual graph of the max-flow algorithm to find the min $s, t$-cut.

Comment: What is your background regarding max-flow algorithms?

Comment: This is the minimum cut problem in an undirected graph, not the minimum $s$-$t$ cut problem in a directed graph.